# How to change language Japan to English Enterprise Architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

My EA language of me is Japan, I dont know Japanese, Could everyonee help me change Jp to English ?
thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you might've downloaded from [Sparxsystems.jp](https://www.sparxsystems.jp/) .

Please download it from [Sparx Systems Australia ( HQ )](http://sparxsystems.com/) .